# Directing HTTP Traffic to a Virtual Host Apache Server

Tags: dns, virtualization

I need the HTML web content of givemeabagofmoney.com to display on bargaingiver.com.

The DNS at givemeabagofmoney.com is set up as a virtual host on my server(details below).  I can publish content on givemeabagofmoney.com with no problems.

Bargaingiver DNS: The NS are set to Cloudflare. In Cloudflare I have set the A record to the IP of givemeabagofmoney.com which is 173.240.15.24

What am I missing?

```
    ServerName givemeabagofmoney.com
    ServerAlias www.givemeabagofmoney.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/givemeabagofmoney.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/givemeabagofmoney.com-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/givemeabagofmoney.com-access.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/html/givemeabagofmoney.com/public_html">
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Try adding `ServerAlias bargaingiver.com`

Comment: Here is what I was missing:

"<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName bargaingiver.com
   ServerAlias www.bargaingiver.com
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/givemeabagofmoney.com/public_html
   ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/bargaingiver.com-error.log
   CustomLog /var/log/httpd/bargaingiver.com-access.log combined

   <Directory "/var/www/html/givemeabagofmoney.com/public_html">
           AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>"